# no error in the project, but I can not see the camera image

Tags: java, image-processing, netbeans, face-detection

Netbeans image processing, there is no error in the project, but the camera does not turn on the blue screen gives

```
    CLKernel[] kernels = buildKernels(fastCompilerOptions, "JavaCV.cl", "pyrDown", "remap", "remapBayer");
    this.pyrDownKernel    = kernels[0];
    this.remapKernel      = kernels[1];
    this.remapBayerKernel = kernels[2];
}
```

not a mistake but I get such warning.

Compilation failed
CLDevice [id: 20385744 name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 type: GPU profile: FULL_PROFILE] build log:
2:85:29: error: scalar operand type has greater rank than the type of the vector element. ('double' and 'float4' (vector of 4 'float' values))
    float4 rgb = (1.0/256.0)*(S(x2-2, y2-2) + S(x2+2, y2-2) + S(x2-2, y2+2) + S(x2+2, y2+2)) +
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2:86:29: error: scalar operand type has greater rank than the type of the vector element. ('double' and 'float4' (vector of 4 'float' values))
                 (4.0/256.0)*(S(x2-1, y2-2) + S(x2+1, y2-2) + S(x2-2, y2-1) + S(x2+2, y2-1) +
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2:88:29: error: scalar operand type has greater rank than the type of the vector element. ('double' and 'float4' (vector of 4 'float' values))
                 (6.0/256.0)*(S(x2  , y2-2) + S(x2-2, y2  ) + S(x2+2, y2  ) + S(x2  , y2+2)) +
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2:89:29: error: scalar operand type has greater rank than the type of the vector element. ('double' and 'float4' (vector of 4 'float' values))
                (16.0/256.0)*(S(x2-1, y2-1) + S(x2+1, y2-1) + S(x2-1, y2+1) + S(x2+1, y2+1)) +
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2:90:29: error: scalar operand type has greater rank than the type of the vector element. ('double' and 'float4' (vector of 4 'float' values))
                (24.0/256.0)*(S(x2  , y2-1) + S(x2-1, y2  ) + S(x2+1, y2  ) + S(x2  , y2+1)) +

```
2:91:29: error: scalar operand type has greater rank than the type of the vector element. ('double' and 'float4' (vector of 4 'float' values))
                (36.0/256.0)* S(x2  , y2  );
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ [error: CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE]
    at com.jogamp.opencl.CLException.newException(CLException.java:84)
    at com.jogamp.opencl.CLProgram.build(CLProgram.java:392)
    at com.jogamp.opencl.CLProgram.build(CLProgram.java:273)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.JavaCVCL.buildKernels(JavaCVCL.java:251)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.JavaCVCL.buildKernels(JavaCVCL.java:233)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.JavaCVCL.<init>(JavaCVCL.java:162)`enter code here`
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.JavaCVCL.<init>(JavaCVCL.java:105)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.GLCanvasFrame.main(GLCanvasFrame.java:325)
```

Comment: Your title states "no error in project" but your question shows "Compilation failed". Can you clarify exactly what your actual question is?

Comment: @skomisa this is a repost of their earlier question.